# SSH authentication using gpg-agent and another source for keys?

Tags: openssh, gnupg, ssh-agent, gpg-agent

**tl;dr:** *Is there a way to either disable the persistent import functionality of `gpg-agent` or work around that to allow using different sources for SSH keys?*

### Situation

I use **GnuPG 2 keys** (on a YubiKey) for SSH authentication through `gpg-agent`'s `enable-ssh-support`. This works fine.

I do have **other keys** available (filesystem and KeePassXC). When using `ssh-add` or KeePassXC to add those, they are imported by `gpg-agent` and stored in `~/.gnupg/private-keys-v1.d/`. I need to provide an additional password for encrypting those.

### The problem

This works as advertised, but defeats the purpose of having keys stored elsewhere:

- I want KeePassXC to **temporarily add keys** to the current `ssh-agent` when it unlocks the password database. The keys shouldn't be permanently available afterwards.
- Similar for `ssh-add`ing key files from the shell: I do not want to import and persist those while having to provide even more passwords.

How do I avoid the import while allowing all sources of keys to be used? One idea that I was having was to set up multiple agents on the same machine, possibly `gpg-agent` forwarding to a local `ssh-agent`, but this sounds like it may be overly complicated.

A similar problem is part of [this KeePassXC issue](https://github.com/keepassxreboot/keepassxc/issues/2029), but no solution was suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Third option: Instead of using the Yubikey via gpg-agent, use its PIV smartcard support via PKCS#11. This is natively supported by OpenSSH via `PKCS11Provider`:

```
ssh -I opensc-pkcs11.so root@myhost
```

ssh-agent can be made aware of PKCS#11 keys as well:

```
ssh-add -s opensc-pkcs11.so
```

(Yubico also provides its own Yubikey-specific `libykcs11.so` module as part of yubico-piv-tool, but as the latter is now deprecated, I would assume that libykcs11.so is also deprecated and that you should just use OpenSC's generic PIV support. In practice the two modules are interchangeable and will recognize each other's objects without any problems.)

Note that Yubikey's OpenPGP and PIV applets are completely separate and you cannot move a key between them, so if it's a hardware-generated keypair you'll unfortunately need to create a new one using `ykman piv`. (Yubikey allows you to import software-generated keys though.)

1. Set a PIN (and a PUK for unblocking a forgotten PIN). Both must be alphanumeric, and must be 6–8 characters long:

   ```
   ykman piv change-pin -P 123456
   ykman piv change-puk -p 12345678
   ```
2. Generate a key, together with a self-signed certificate (which SSH won't care about):

   ```
   ykman piv info
   ykman piv generate-key -a ECCP256 9a /tmp/9a.pub
   ykman piv generate-certificate 9a /tmp/9a.pub -s "Thomas" -d 3650
   rm /tmp/9a.pub
   ```

   In case you don't have the newer `ykman`, you can use the older `yubico-piv-tool` or even various generic PKCS#11 tools (e.g. OpenSC `pkcs11-tool` or GnuTLS `p11tool`):

   ```
   yubico-piv-tool -a change-pin -P 123456
   yubico-piv-tool -a change-puk -P 12345678
   yubico-piv-tool -a status
   yubico-piv-tool -a generate -A ECCP256 -s 9a -o /tmp/9a.pub
   yubico-piv-tool -a verify-pin -a selfsign-certificate \
                   -s 9a -S "/CN=Thomas" -i /tmp/9a.pub -o /tmp/9a.crt
   yubico-piv-tool -a import-certificate -s 9a -i /tmp/9a.crt
   ```
3. Export the public key in authorized_keys format:

   ```
   ssh-keygen -D opensc-pkcs11.so > Yubikey.pub
   ```
4. Use the `ssh -I` option or the `PKCS11Provider` setting when connecting. (You will be prompted for the smartcard PIN every time – set up SSH connection multiplexing if needed to reduce this.)

This approach has other advantages: it is very easy to use on Windows as well, due to Windows already having a driver for PIV smartcards (e.g. through PuTTY-CAC or several other projects which bridge CAPI/CNG key storage to SSH clients).

Comment: Given that this does not depend on gpg-agent and I am not actually forced to use PGP, this sounds like a good alternative. Also, didn't know that PKCS#11 works with ECC. Forwarding to WSL2 seems to be possible, too. Thanks, will return to this answer once I tried it.

Comment: The API does support ECC, it's just that many smartcards don't. You can use `pkcs11-tool --module <path> --list-mechanisms` to see what is supported by a specific device. (Note that for some Yubikey models, the OpenPGP applet and the PIV applet can actually differ in algorithm support even though the hardware is the same.)

Comment: One more thing to keep in mind: PIV has designated [key slots](https://developers.yubico.com/PIV/Introduction/Certificate_slots.html) with different PIN policies. Some slots require a PIN for every single operation (9c), others only once per session (9a), others don't require a PIN at all (9e). In the NEO they are hardcoded; in the 5 they are customizable. I'll eventually add this to the post.

Comment: After looking into the `gpg-agent` source code I feel this is the most viable alternative solution, even if it might be possible to have gpg-agent forward to a local ssh-agent with some hackery. PIV is somewhat clunky with the PKCS setup, but works. U2F looks like a simple alternative, but many servers (OpenSSH <8.2) and tools like KeePassXC don't yet support for that. Still need to check whether an Android SSH client can use PIV and U2F, guess there might be no access to the device.

Comment: My phone has its own software-based key that has minimal access, which I use to connect to a server which has a TPM holding a second copy of the "full access" key (PIN-protected).